# matplotlibのplt.scatterでエラーunhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'が出る

Tags: python, python3, numpy, matplotlib

初歩的な質問ですみません。
matplotlibで散布図を作成しようとした際に発生したエラーです。

実験の生データを読み込んだ後に加工して、下記のようなデータフレームを作成しました。

df1（401行×1列）
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

df2（401行×1列）
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

コードとしては質問欄にある1個目の表を df1、二個目の表を df2 に入れていて、下記のようにコードを記載していました。

```
plt.scatter(df1, df2)
```

コード実行後に `unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'` のエラーが発生していました。

このエラーの解決方法、この2つのデータフレームからのグラフの作成方法を教えて頂けないでしょうか。

Comment: この辺の記事のどれかが参考になるかも。[Plotting multiple scatter plots pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43061768/9014308), [multiple scatter plots with matplotlib and strings on the x-axis.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48380953/9014308), [Multiple scatter plots with two colorbars](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56080777/9014308), [MatPlotLib: Multiple datasets on the same scatter plot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4270301/9014308)

Comment: 「質問欄にある1個目の表を df1、二個目の表を df2 に入れていて」の部分のコードを質問文に追記していただくことはできますでしょうか？　多分そこに問題があると思うのですが、今のままだと推測するしかなく……。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

そのエラー(おそらく正確には`TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'`でしょう)は、df1[51]またはdf2[41]のどちらかが文字列の場合に発生するでしょう。
表示されたデータフレームからすると、df2[41]の方が文字列と思われます。

両方とも文字列の場合はエラーは発生しないようです。

以下で確認できます。

```
print(df1.dtypes)
print(df2.dtypes)
```

おそらく以下のように表示されるでしょう。

```
41    object
dtype: object
```

そうしたら、以下のように変換すれば使えるようになるでしょう。

```
df2[41] = df2[41].astype(np.float64)
```

もしdf1[51]の方が文字列だった場合はこちらで変換します。

```
df1[51] = df1[51].astype(np.int64)
```

その後に以下を実行すれば正常に終了するはずです。

```
plt.scatter(df1, df2)
```