# matplotlibを使った作図でエラー unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

VSCodeで以下のプログラムを実行するとエラーメッセージが表示されグラフが表示されません。解決法がありましたら教えて下さい

**エラー**

```
例外が発生しました: TypeError unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

**コード:**

```
import pandas as pd
df =pd.read_csv("csvファイルのパス")
df.head()
x = [['x']]
y = [['y']]
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

plt.plot(x, y, 'o')
plt.show()
```

Comment: 過去の類似質問: [matplotlibのplt.scatterでエラーunhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'が出る](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/70620)

Answer (score 1):

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv("csvファイルのパス")
df.head()

plt.plot(df['x'], df['y'], 'o')
plt.show()
```

また、`pandas.DataFrame` クラスには [pandas.DataFrame.plot — pandas 1.5.2 documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) メソッドがありますので、それを使う場合は以下の様になります。

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv("csvファイルのパス")
df.head()

df.plot(x='x', y='y', kind='scatter', marker='o')
plt.show()
```